# excel hide empty cells in range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do something simple and hide a row if all data in that row is empty. This is what i have so far.

```
Sub UpdateFields_630()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("630 BOM")

Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim rng As Range, c As Range

On Error GoTo 0

With sht3
    Set rng = Cells

    LastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

    LastCol = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

    For Each c In Range(Cells(9, "E"), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    If c.Value = "" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    Next
End With

sht3.Protect

Set rng = Nothing
Set sht3 = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

> Before Sort

[image: before]

> After Sort

[image: after]

Rows 13,14,19,20 and 38 are being hidden with this code for some reason and can't figure out why.

I can get this to work if i hide based on `column "A" total = 0` but then row rows `27 & 30` will hide. I've tried `If c.Value = "x" Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False` and that didn't seem to do anything.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Instead of check if the cell value is "", check if the length of the cell value is 0.

Comment: @RichHolton How would i do this? haven't used `LEN` in VBA before. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You're hiding the row if *any* of its cells is empty, not if *all* of them are empty

2- You're not qualifying your ranges, making your with clause useless.

You can use `Application.CountA` to check if all the cells of a range are empty. Apply it on each row to decide if it should be hidden.

```
    '             v            v (notice these dots)
    For Each c In .Range("E9", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Rows
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = Application.CountA(c) = 0
    Next
```

**EDIT**

since the blank cells have formula, `CountA` wont count then as blank. For this reason use this instead:

```
    For Each c In .Range("E9", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Rows
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = Application.CountIf(c, "") = c.Cells.Count
    Next
```

Comment: im still very new to VBA, still learning. Thanks for the input. Your code applied to my loop doesn't do anything. i think i am missing something.

Comment: @MattTaylor step through it with the debugger, check calues of `lastRow` and `lastCol`. Also be specific with the ranges: `Set rng = .Cells` (dot before Cells, meaning `sht3.Cells`).

Comment: @ASH i have stepped thru it many times before posting here. The selection range of `lastrow & lastcol` selects the entire range that its supposed to. It seems to be only checking the `lastcol` for data and hidding everything else.

Comment: Are these blank cells result of formulas, or really empty?

Comment: They all have formulas in them

Comment: @MattTaylor Ok, `CountA` doesnt count blanks as empty if they have formula. Try the edit.